# VBA Loop for filling worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data into a template but I am unsure how I create one line that includes all ranges and cells to make my code smaller. Right now I use 13 lines to fill out one of 20 products in the template. Can anyone help with this? Much appreciated

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = ""

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select File"
    .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls?"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
If Len(FileName) < 4 Then Exit Sub 'No file selected

Dim TempWorkbook As Workbook, currentSheet As Worksheet
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet 'Store the ActiveSheet, it will change
Set TempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

     For Index = 8 To 11

            currentSheet.Range("T" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 2).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("U" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 4).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("V" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 9).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("W" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 13).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("X" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 17).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("Y" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 21).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            currentSheet.Range("Z" & Index).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((Index + 10), 25).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)

      Next
```

NEW EDIT:

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = ""

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select File"
    .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls?"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
If Len(FileName) < 4 Then Exit Sub 'No file selected

Dim TempWorkbook As Workbook, currentSheet As Worksheet
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet 'Store the ActiveSheet, it will change
Set TempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
Dim TempSheet As Worksheet: Set TempSheet = TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM")
Dim i As Double
Dim Index As Double
Dim arrz As Variant
arrz = Array(2, 4, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 30, 36, 37, 38, 39)
For Index = 8 To 11
        For i = 20 To 32
                currentSheet.Cells(Index, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempSheet.Cells((Index + 10), arrz(i - 39)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
                currentSheet.Cells((Index + 7), i).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempSheet.Cells((Index + 21), arrz(i - 39)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
        Next i
Next Index
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any logic to this number increasing? `").Cells((Index + 10), `2`).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)` It increases by 2 first, then by 4 every time in your example. If this were a constant increase it'd be easy to do. If not, it'll get a lot more difficult.

Comment: There is also one jump by 5, from 4 to 9. It would be possible to create an array of those column numbers `[2, 4, 9, 13, ...]` and loop through the columns that way but it's not that much simpler and only a few lines of code less.

Comment: @Plutian Yes. The cells it copies from are +4 every time except for the first one (being 2)

Comment: @M. Schalk yes thats true. But the first two lines are country and SAP code. After that its +4 everytime. But isn't it possible to have a definition and then say "(Index +10),2 +2 + 4 + 9 + 13 + 17 etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to do the two blocks in a single loop instead with some maths, and also to dim the worksheets so they work with my test. Obviously you change these to the sheets you need.

```
Sub Copy()
Dim FileName As String
FileName = ""

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select File"
    .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls?"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
If Len(FileName) < 4 Then Exit Sub 'No file selected

Dim TempWorkbook As Workbook, currentSheet As Worksheet
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet 'Store the ActiveSheet, it will change
Set TempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
Dim TempSheet As Worksheet: Set TempSheet = TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM")
Dim i As Double
Dim Index As Double
Dim arrz As Variant
arrz = Array(2, 4, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39)
For Index = 8 To 11
        For i = 20 To 32
        currentSheet.Cells(Index, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempSheet.Cells((Index + 10), arrz(i - 20)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
        currentSheet.Cells((Index + 7), i).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempSheet.Cells((Index + 21), arrz(i - 20)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
        Next i
Next Index
End Sub
```

**Edited as per comments:** added file picker and proper sheet references for such. Tested and works on my machine.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I am trying to make it work but I think I am doing something wrong with my definitions in the beginning. I edited my code. Can you maybe edit your code to match what I have? I made it so I can choose the document which I really love.

Comment: @Christian Answer amended as requested. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, first thank you a lot for writing the above! However, for some reason it doesnt copy any values into the document nor give me an error.

Comment: @Christian Please check the following: In the currentsheet (the one you called the macro from) the range H21 to K29 should now be filled with formulas as so `='C:\yourfilepath\[yourfilename.xlsx]FINAL FORM'!$B$18`. Please also check whether the opened file in range B18 to AG21 has the data you are looking to copy.

Comment: @Christian Also, if you are looking to copy the value itself rather than a formula, then this method can be adapted by changing this bit `.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)` to `.value` instead. Although some more bits need to be edited as well so let me know if you want me to adapt my answer to this.

Comment: Arh I see! I found the numbers hidden in H-K. But where in the code is H-K stated (just for my understanding sorry)? Also the numbers are copied horizontal and not vertical and is also copied into row column 21 instead of 8. So first number needs to be in "U8". I hope it makes sense, again thanks!

Comment: @Christian I see, somehow the values for index and i got swapped around in the target cells. I have now swapped them, and the cells now get copied starting with U8. Also H and K (were) derived from the `i` double, calling it as the column in a R1C1 cell reference. Example: `Cells(i,2)` for i is 2, references column 2 row 2, or `B2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are the true MVP.

Comment: You're very welcome. I probably learned as much from this question as you (maybe even more), so thank you for asking as well.

Comment: @Christian done. Seems like you've realised your mistake though as you deleted your comment. No worries!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you're asking, looks a bit cleaner:

```
Dim arr() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
arr = Array(2, 4, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25)

For cl = 20 To 26
    For rw = 8 To 11
        currentSheet.Cells(rw, cl).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((rw + 10), arr(cl - 20)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    Next

    For rw = 15 To 18
        currentSheet.Cells(rw, cl).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells((rw + 14), arr(cl - 20)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    Next
Next
```