# Is it possible to replace part of the code with list or array values in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I use follow below shown code to extract Crystal Ball simulation results to certain cells. In that code, parameter_1_(A/B/C/D) are certain Ranges which have been pre defined and I have ~20 of this type parameters. What would be the best way to loop in order replace parameter_1 with parameter_n in both sides of "="?

Thanks in advance.

```
parameter_1_A.offset(0, -1) = CB.GetAssumPercent(parameter_1_A, 0.1)
parameter_1_B.offset(0, -1) = CB.GetAssumPercent(parameter_1_B, 0.1)
parameter_1_C.offset(0, -1) = CB.GetAssumPercent(parameter_1_C, 0.1)
parameter_1_D.offset(0, -1) = CB.GetAssumPercent(parameter_1_D, 0.1)
```

Comment: Could you show a snippet of how the ranges are assigned. If there is a certain logic to it it might be easier to skip having those 20-something different `Range` objects.

Comment: I would put the list of parameters inside of an array, and then loop through the array.

Comment: To further @Damian comment, this is exactly what was done [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58112371/11936678). Might be worth a read for you.